# LAN8720A + ESP32 (GPIO 0 Clk Out) RX working, TX not

Tags: circuit-design, ethernet, esp32

I have made a custom board with the ESP32-WROVER-IE module and the LAN8720A Ethernet PHY. RX'ing packets work (I see ARP packets etc.), but TX (and therefore DHCP and communication) won't work (I ran tcpdump on a machine directly connected to the board).

The clock for the LAN8720 is provided via GPIO 0, because GPIO 16/17 are used for the PSRAM. The trace for the clock is ca. 15-20mm long.

Datasheet for the Jack with magnetics: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811141815_HANRUN-Zhongshan-HanRun-Elec-HR911105A_C12074.pdf

What could be the issue about RX working but TX not?

Update: Added board layout. The board was assembled by JLCPCB.

[image: ethrnet]
[image: esp32]
[image: board layout excerpt]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the magnetics are reversed and should have the CM choke side towards the cable connector,

Comment: I have updated my question. I am just wondering where the error lies and how I could fix it. As far as I understand, if the clock signal would be not clean, then RX would also not work.

Comment: the schematic was not clear to me, but they are not reversed after looking at the PDF. and seeing now your jack is on the right side.  Do you know how to scope signal integrity with 2 probes?

Comment: I don't have a fast enough scope here currently. I can only check with my Logic Analyser (DSLogic) for now, but not sure if that is of any help. Part of the PCB layout is now attached above (I can also share the EasyEDA Project).

Comment: Looks like DSL might work with dual analog channels using math ch 1-2  But 1st check logic functions of TxEn D1 D0 in and out

Comment: I will be able to check that tomorrow morning. I just found this remark:

ETH_CLOCK_GPIO0_OUT  - 50MHz clock from internal APLL output on GPIO0 - possibly an inverter is needed for LAN8720

Is it possible that the LAN8720A actually needs an inverted clock?

Comment: ? I don't know if that is needed for buffering or phase sync ?

Comment: Apparntly my problem is that the clock from gpio0 should be inverted (and buffered) and the ESP32 boot gpio from the uart should be a low capacitive load.